# Exporting interpolating functions to excel

Tags: export, interpolation, excel

I have a question about exporting an `InterpolatingFunction` to Excel. I checked the forum, but I still couldn't completely understand how to solve my problem. Could someone help me with this problem?

```
a = 10^-2;
eq1 = {hf'[t] == -a*(hf[t] - hs[t]),hs'[t] == a*(hf[t] - hs[t]), hf[0] == 20, hs[0] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eq1, {hf, hs}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

The I got solution for `hf[t]` & `hs[t]` :

```
{{hf -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>],
  hs -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>]}}
```

I'm wondering how I can export `hf[t]` & `hs[t]` values to excel as t ranges from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a = 10^-2;
eq1 = {hf'[t] == -a*(hf[t] - hs[t]), hs'[t] == a*(hf[t] - hs[t]),  hf[0] == 20, hs[0] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eq1, {hf, hs}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Now:

```
Plot[{hf[t], hs[t]} /. sol1, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Export["c:\\test.xls", Table[Flatten[{t, hf[t], hs[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 100}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear answer!

Comment: How can I control my values of the x-axis? Let's say I need am plotting a graph from 1 to 2 and need 1000 equally spaced points, how can I ask mathematical to give me the function value at 1000 equally spaced points?

Answer (score 15):

The interpolating functions that `NDSolve` returns contain an irregular grid that reflects which points were used to calculate the solution. Not always, but often this grid is a better choice than a regular grid as you would generate with `Table` when exporting. Here is how you could export the data as `NDSolve` generated it:

```
a = 10^-2;
eq1 = {hf'[t] == -a*(hf[t] - hs[t]), hs'[t] == a*(hf[t] - hs[t]), 
   hf[0] == 20, hs[0] == 0};
sol1 = NDSolve[eq1, {hf, hs}, {t, 0, 100}]

hfsol = hf /. First[sol1]
hssol = hs /. First[sol1]

data = {#, hfsol[#], hssol[#]} & /@ First[hfsol@"Coordinates"]
Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "sol.xlsx"}], data]
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you have done in the second last line of the code? I also want finer grid points, hence would be beneficial if I can understand what you did to use it in my case.

Comment: `hfsol` and `hssol` are `InterpolatingFunction` objects. These do have some properties (or methds) defined, one of them is `"Coordinates"` which gives a list of all time values in this case. I do create a matrix containing the time, the value of `hfsol` and the value of `hssol` in each row. That is the data that will be exported. By refering to the `"Coordinates"` property of the `InterpolatingFunction` object, we use the same time steps that were used to determine the solution.