# Exporting summation of interpolating functions to excel

Tags: plotting, export

I search the forum and found a question about exporting interpolating functions to excel. Unfortunately, I can't use it to export the results to excel. This is the equation :

`u = StateResponse[ssm,  UnitStep[t] , {t, 0, 1},Method -> {"NDSolve", MaxSteps -> 1600000}]`

and the answer is :

`11.2822InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t]+0.1206InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t]+34.117InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t]+2.335InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t]+63.1235InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t]+5.8206InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t]`

I would appreciate that someone can help me to export this equation to a excel file.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19507/exporting-interpolating-functions-to-excel

Comment: @ PlatoManiac : Unfortunately, It's not possible for me to mention my ` ssm ` .Beside that,if I could do that, my ` ssm ` would be a huge matrix that I wouldn't be able to provide it here.

Comment: When I use the procedure mentioned in ` http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19507/exporting-interpolating-functions-to-excel?rq=1 `, it give me a Excel file only with 2 data!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem is implicitly hidden in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19507/exporting-interpolating-functions-to-excel) as I mentioned in the comment.Lets take an example problem!

```
res = StateResponse[
StateSpaceModel[{{{-3, 3/2, -1}, {-2, 1, -2}, {-1, 3, -2}}, {{1,0}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}},
{{1, 0, -1}}, {{0, 0}}}, 
SamplingPeriod -> None,SystemsModelLabels -> None], {SquareWave[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 20}];
```

Also assume that the following is a summation expression you are interested in.

```
SeedRandom[123];
exp = Total[res^2 RandomReal[1, {3}]]
```

> 0.977826 InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>][t]^2+0.455719 InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>][t]^2+0.943215 InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},<>][t]^2

Now we export the expression `exp` defined in terms of `InterpolatingFunction` to an Excel data file as below

```
fun[k_] := exp /. t -> k;
tval = Range[0, 20, .01]; (*How often you want to record the values*)
Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "sol.xlsx"}],Transpose@{tval,fun/@tval}];
```

Now test if things are working fine. Left one is directly from *Mathematica* and the right one after importing from the excel file we generated above followed by a consecutive interpolation.

```
impfun = Interpolation[
First@Import[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "sol.xlsx"}],"Data"]];
GraphicsRow[Plot[#[t], {t, 0, 20}, Frame -> True] & /@ {fun, impfun},ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: @ PlatoManiac : It works my friend!! I really appreciate you for it.

Comment: You are welcome. The trick if you are new with Mathematica is be persistent and do not loose hope quickly!