# Save output of NDSolve to a file

Tags: differential-equations, export

I am solving following differential equation using Mathematica,

```
s = NDSolve[{u''[x] == (42/10)*Sin[x]*Sin[x]*u[x], u[-3] == 0, 
   u'[3] == 1}, u, {x, -3, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 22, 
  InterpolationOrder -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[{u[x] /. s}, {x, -3, 3}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "v(x)"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I would like to plot this output with gnuplot (as all of the other figure in my report are generated using gnuplot) to be consistent. How can I generate file
with $x$ and $u(x)$ values written in 2 columns?

I tried to write output in a file,

```
  sW = OpenWrite["out.dat", FormatType -> TraditionalForm];
    $Output = {sW};
    Write[sW, x, Evaluate[u[x] /. s], {x, -3, 3, 1}]
    Close[sW];
```

But this does not print values of $u(x)$

Comment: You can grab the actual points used by `Plot` with `Cases[plot, _Line, Infinity][[1, 1]]`.  BTW, not part of your question, but you should use `Export` instead of raw `Open/Write` operations.

Comment: Have you seen this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19507/169)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After solving your DE, do
`Table[{x, u[x]} /. %, {x, -3, 3, 0.01}]` and save the output to a file "u.dat", which should make it a double column table.