# How can I save the data from NDsolve in a .txt file?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm quite new to mathematica so I'm not really that sure what I'm doing. I'm trying to record the following data from the NDsolve function. However, I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
sigma = -3;
rho = 26.5;
beta = 1.0;
s = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == sigma*(x[t] - y[t]), 
    Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t] z[t] + rho* x[t] - y[t], 
    Derivative[1][z][t] == x[t] y[t] - beta*z[t], x[0] == z[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 400}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 400}, 
    PlotPoints -> 1000, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[.8, 0, 0]], 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", #4] &)], 
Graphics3D[{ColorData["SolarColors"][0], 
Sphere[First[({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s) /. t -> 0], .75]}], 
RotationAction -> "Clip", Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> False, 
    Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

I've been reading this thread ([Save output of NDSolve to a file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59434/save-output-of-ndsolve-to-a-file)), however, I can't get it to work when adding the table after NDSolve has been used. It just writes x,y,z,t to the screen!

Thanks!

Edit: I've added these lines after the ones above and it still hasn't worked.

```
 Directory[]
 FileNameJoin[{"~/", "WolframDir"}]
 Export["testfile.txt", 
 Table[{t, x[t]} /. %, {x, -3, 3, 0.01}, "Data"]
```

Comment: Igor wrote that you also have to export. E.g. try `Export["bla.txt",Table[{x, u[x]} /. %, {x, -3, 3, 0.01},"Data"]`.

Comment: So I've added that line after the code, and it seems to run but I can't find any data file called "bla.txt" in my directory where the original code is stored. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Then execute `Directory[]` and look in the path that gets returned. You can also specify any other path by changing `"bla.txt"` to whatever you want.

Comment: So I've added `Directory[]
Export["~/WolframDir/test2.txt", 
 Table[{x, u[x]} /. %, {x, -3, 3, 0.01}, "Data"]` and I still can't find the data. I must be missing something really simple! 
 `

Comment: *facepalm*. So by specifying a concrete path, you invalidated my advice. If you export to `"~/WolframDir/test2.txt"`, then you have to look in `FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "WolframDir"}]`.

Comment: So I've added the following lines above, as shown in the edit, and it still doesn't seem to work. Any silly mistakes that there that someone new to Mathematica would do?

Comment: Try `curve = t \[Function] Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s[[1]]];
data = Table[Join[{t}, curve[t]], {t, 0, 400, .005}];
Export["testfile.dat", data, "Data"];`.