# How do I remove {} in a exported .txt file?

Tags: export

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19508/8822) answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19507/8822) question, teaches us how to export the result of `NDSolve` to an Excel file. It is easyly adapted to the case I want a .txt file:

```
Export["c:\\test.txt", Table[Flatten[{t, hf[t], hs[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 100}]]
```

But in this way the file has unwanted parenthesis `{}` in every row:

```
{0, 20., 0.}
{1, 19.80198672353379, 0.19801327646620656}
{2, 19.607894374473258, 0.3921056255267404}
{3, 19.41764531409662, 0.5823546859033791}
[...]
```

How do I remove the `{}`? I tried playng with `Flatten`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to play with the export format (see export documentation). For example Export["c:\\test.txt", Table[Flatten[{t, hf[t], hs[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 100}],"Table"] does the trick. However, ".txt" does not accept some  format (e.g. "Data"), but you can use .dat instead for example

Comment: If it’s only a few files you can use find and replace all in notepad.

Comment: Don't export as .txt. Export as .csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Export["c:\\test.txt", Table[Flatten[{t, hf[t], hs[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 100}]，"Table"]`?

Comment: I would use "CSV", but "Table" should also work fine here.